# Copying records from one table to another of different SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have same table on both server with 15 columns.first table has less records than second. I want to copy remaining records from second table to first. Both tables are on different SQL server. So I have created linked server. I was thinking about IF EXISTS. But i want to copy more records. I want to create script for this task. and I will use this frequently using task scheduler.(Note: I don't want to use Replication)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Except Operator 
For Example

```
Drop table #aa
Create table #aa (Id Int)

Insert into #aa
Select 1

Drop table #bb
Create table #bb (Id Int)

Insert into #bb
Select 1
Union all
Select 2


Insert into #aa
Select * from #bb
Except
Select * from #aa
```